# Python nested loops into one line

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, list-comprehension

I need to clean a list of strings containing names. I need to remove titles and then things like 's etc. The code works ok but I'd like to transform it to two comprehension lists. My attempts like this one `[name.replace(e, '') for name in names_ for e in replace]` didn't work, I'm definitely missing something. Will appreciate your help!

```
names = ['Mrs Marple', 'Maj Gen Smith', "Tony Dobson's"]
replace = ['Mrs ', 'Maj ', 'Gen ']
names_new = []
for name in names:
    for e in replace:
        name = name.replace(e, '')
    names_new.append(name)
names_final = []
for name in names_new:
    if name.endswith("'s"):
        name = name[:-2]
        names_final.append(name)
    else:
        names_final.append(name)
print(names_final)
```

Comment: I think the problem is due to `name = name.replace(e, '')`, in comprehensions we're not able to do that as `replace()` method is not inplace

Comment: and we can't do replace inplace as `string` is immutable in python

Comment: please check the answer that I have added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) to do exactly what you want:

```
import re

names = ['Mrs Marple', 'Maj Gen Smith', "Tony Dobson's"]
replace = ['Mrs ', 'Maj ', 'Gen ']
names = [re.sub(r'(Mrs\s|Maj\s|Gen\s|\'s$)', '', x) for x in names]
print(names)
```

Output:

```
['Marple', 'Smith', 'Tony Dobson']
```

Comment: Well, this won't work if we have multiple  elements in replace, or for that matter if the replace list is generated on the fly

Comment: I meant what if the list `replace` is generated during runtime. In this particular example we have limited elements in `replace` and hence we're able to generate ` regex for it.

Comment: Yes, that's my problem. The `replace` list is much much longer than in the example above and might be modified...

Comment: I also need to remove `'s` when it shows at the end of the string only.

Comment: @aviss I updated the regex to only look for `'s` at the end of the string.  This is just an example of how to approach this.  You would need to expand the regex to match everything you want to replace. I can't create that regex since I don't know what your entire replace list is.

Comment: Thanks @chrisz, this is definitely very useful and answers the question as formulated :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is due to `name = name.replace(e, '')` statement in the for loop, and as we can't use assignment operator in comprehensions, you used `name.replace(e, '')` but again `replace()` method is not inplace as the `string` in python is not mutable.

Solution I that I have written is based on using reduce, here were replacing all the occurrences of elements in sequence `replace`.

```
from functools import reduce
names = ['Mrs Marple', 'Maj Gen Smith', "Tony Dobson's"]
replace = ['Mrs ','Maj ','Gen ']
result = [reduce(lambda str, e: str.replace(e, ''), replace, name) for name in names]
```

Here is the result

```
print(result)
['Marple', 'Smith', "Tony Dobson's"]
```

The solution by @chrisz works but if `replace` list is generated on the fly or is too long, we won't be able to form a regex for it. This solution works pretty much in any scenario.

Comment: Yes! It is the best solution for the `replace` part and I can use regex to remove `'s`. If only I could accept two answers!